# Am I editing wrong?

Tags: discussion, edits

Several people thought that this edit...

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6435972

...did not make the question even a little easier to read.

Am I wrong, here?  What am I missing?

Comment: That's a pretty big "meh" case. You'll be 2k soon enough.

Comment: I think you're editing wrong. First thing that springs to mind is you missed to remove "Hello I am very new to everything I am attempting to do here, I will try to be as detailed as possible with my problem." (see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/165773))

Comment: While capitalizing HTML and Google is a nice thing to do *along with something else*, I fail to see how that actually makes a post easier to read. I mean, if you're going to be a stickler about capitalization, "Google Visualization" is the formal name of an API and both words should be capitalized. You also didn't capitalize in the title.

Comment: I would have rejected your edits as _too minor_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you forget that the *too minor* option doesn't exist anymore.  The reject reason here is probably just a carry over from the fact that the too minor option was removed

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ah, THX for the enlightment! I didn't work with the edit review queue for a longer time. I wasn't aware that reject reason was abandoned.

Comment: I think `Changes are either completely superfluous` applies to what you tried to edit. Overall the edit queue is large enough so there is no reason to burden the reviewers with trivial edits.

Answer (score 6):

Suggested edits need to be reviewed and approved by three people. Save the exceedingly minor edits like that for when you're able to edit posts directly rather than taking up the time of reviewers.